# Ayuda obtener el residuo en python

Tags: python

Me sale este error y no se por que es:

> ```
> line 15, in toBinario
>     residuo = ip%2
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> ```

Este es mi código:

```
def toBinario(ip):
    binarios = []
    residuo = 0
    resultado = 0

    while True:
        residuo = ip%2
        resultado = ip/2
        ip = resultado
        binarios.append(residuo)
        print(binarios)
        if len(binarios) < 1:
            break
```

Comment: Seguramente `ip` es una cadena (`str`) por lo que el operador `%` se interpreta dentro del contexto de formato de cadenas y no como el operador módulo entre enteros.  El casting debe hacerse antes de aplicar el módulo `residuo = int(ip) % 2`. Sería bueno que añadieras un ejemplo de entrada y la salida esperada y explicaras que pretendes hacer con ese código para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @FJSevilla Gracias amigo ese era el problema...muchas gracias

Comment: De nada @Fernado. Por curiosidad ¿Que estas intentando hacer? Lo digo porque parece una conversión a binario de un entero en Python 2, aunque ese ciclo infinito me despista. Si es eso hay formas mucho más directas de hacerlo en una sola línea vía `bin` o `format` por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

El error traducido libremente viene a decir:

> **Error de tipado**: no todos los argumentos fueron convertidos durante el formateo de la cadena.

Esto nos da en realidad la clave, **formateo** de **cadena**. Lo que está pasando es que a la función se le está pasando una cadena (`str`) por lo que `ip` es una cadena y por tanto en `residuo = ip%2` el operador `%` no se interpreta como el operador módulo en el contexto de dos enteros, es interpretado en el contexto del [formateo básico de cadenas](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) al estilo de C (*operator de interpolación*):

```
>>> "12345%d" % 2
'123452'
```

Como la cadena que se recibe (ip) no contiene ningún especificador que determine el tipo y posición donde incrustar el `2`,  como si ocurre en el ejemplo anterior, el formateo no se puede llevar a cabo y nos muestra el error mencionado.

Es importante recordar que Python es un lenguaje de tipado dinámico pero **fuertemente tipado**, es decir el intérprete no tiene problemas en inferir el tipo del valor al que apunta una variable cuando la declaramos:

```
>>> s = "1"  # tipo str
>>> i = 1    # tipo int
```

Lo que no va ha hacer nunca es modificar el tipo de una variable para "adaptarla" al contexto u operador que se le aplica de forma implícita. Esto es lógicamente una característica de diseño con vistas a la seguridad y a uno de los principios del lenguaje: "explícito mejor que implícito". En este caso `ip` es una cadena y el operador % se interpreta en ese contexto, en cambio la siguiente línea nos da un error aún más claro:

```
>>> ip = "123"
>>> resultado = ip/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    resultado = ip/2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Python nos obliga por tanto a hacer el casting a `int` de forma explícita. En tu caso, o bien haces el casting antes de pasar el argumento a la función, que es quizás lo más lógico:

```
i = int(i)
b = toBinario(i)
```

O haces el casting dentro de la función:

```
def toBinario(ip):
    ip = int(ip)
```

---

Aparentemente intentas realizar una conversión de `int` a su representación en binario. Tu función más o menos hace eso, pero el problema es que nunca rompes el ciclo, debería ser algo así:

```
def to_binary(n):
    bits = []

    while n:
        bit = n % 2
        n //= 2
        bits.append(str(bit))
    bits.reverse()
    return ''.join(bits)
```

El operador `/` en Python 2 retorna la división entera si ambos operandos son enteros, en Python 3 retorna siempre la división real. Esta es la causa de usar `//` (división entera).

Existen otras posibilidades como:

- Usando operadores a nivel de bit:

  ```
  from collections import deque

  def to_binary(n):
      bits = deque()

      while n:
          bits.insert(0, str(n & 1))
          n >>= 1
      return ''.join(bits)
  ```
- Usando el built-in `bin`:

  ```
  def to_binary(n):
      return(bin(n)[2:])
  ```
- Usando formato de cadenas:

  ```
  def to_binary(n):
      return(format(n, "b"))

  # Python >= 3.6
  def to_binary(n):
      return(f"{n:b}")
  ```

Todas ellas presuponen que `n` es un entero y la salida es una cadena con la representación binaria de la cadena (aunque se podría retornar una lista por ejemplo):

```
>>> to_binary(148)
'10010100'
```